# Trying to define my own type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I am trying to define my own type in Haskell called `Name` which is simply just a `String` (I am defining it separately to make my code more readable). I just write the code like so:

```
type Name = String
```

But when I run the file it's saved in on the GHCI, I get an error that says "parse error on input `type'". Why am I getting this error?

Whole code:

```
module Names where import PhoneBook

type Name = String
```

Comment: The line works for me. Is there something else in that file for which you're getting the error?

Comment: Wrong indentation, most probably. Remember that whitespace is significant in Haskell.

Comment: Tried all different indentations, still same error?

Comment: Make sure you don't get any \t as whitespaces, best practice is to use a editor that let you set the Indent using spaces.

Comment: If it's not a whitespace problem, then I suspect there's a problem with the (non-blank) line immediately prior to this. Can you post that line? Or better yet, a simple but complete example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Or, ideally, just copy-paste the entire file from your editor.

Comment: `Prelude> type T = String    Prelude>` IOW Cannot reproduce.

Comment: I edited the code from your deleted answer into the question for you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. It is most likely a problem with the surrounding white-space or hidden formatting in your editor that is causing the problem!

We could probably solve it directly if you pasted the source code that it's from :)

Answer (score 1):

You need your import statements to be on a separate line to your module declaration. Like this:

```
module Names where

import Phonebook

type Name = String
```

Comment: This answer is not precise: it is not required that imports be on a separate line. However, `where` *does* begin a block -- so later lines must start in the same column as the first non-whitespace, non-comment character that follows it.